# Multiple correct results with Hamcrest (is there an or-matcher?)

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest, matcher

I am relatively new to matchers. I am toying around with [hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/) in combination with JUnit and I kinda like it.

Is there a way, to state that one of multiple choices is correct?

Something like

```
assertThat( result, is( either( 1, or( 2, or( 3 ) ) ) ) ) //does not work in hamcrest
```

The method I am testing returns one element of a collection. The list may contain multiple candidates. My current implementation returns the first hit, but that is not a requirement. I would like my testcase to succeed, if any of the possible candidates is returned. How would you express this in Java?

(I am open to hamcrest-alternatives)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
assertThat(result, anyOf(equalTo(1), equalTo(2), equalTo(3)))
```

From [Hamcrest tutorial](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/tutorial#logical):

> `anyOf` - matches if any matchers match, short circuits (like Java ||)

See also [Javadoc](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/core/AnyOf.html).

Moreover, you could write your own Matcher, which is quite easy to do.

Comment: Looks like oneOf is the most recent.

Comment: Thanks, @Richard. Indeed, `oneOf` sounds like a good option for this case too: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/collection/IsIn.html#oneOf-T...-

Answer (score 88):

marcos is right, but you have a couple other options as well. First of all, there *is* an either/or:

```
assertThat(result, either(is(1)).or(is(2)));
```

but if you have more than two items it would probably get unwieldy. Plus, the typechecker gets weird on stuff like that sometimes. For your case, you could do:

```
assertThat(result, isOneOf(1, 2, 3))
```

or if you already have your options in an array/Collection:

```
assertThat(result, isIn(theCollection))
```

See also [Javadoc](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html).

Comment: Hmmm... for some inexplicable reason my Eclipse environment (which is only about 6 months old) has an ancient Hamcrest library and I don't get these goodies.

Comment: Well, `assertThat((Set<String>)null, is(either(empty()).or(nullValue())));` gives me a rather strange assertion error: `Expected: is (an empty collection or null) but: was null` for hamcrest `1.3`...

Comment: isOneOf() seems to be deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `anyOf`, you could also go for the either option, but it has a slightly different syntax:

```
assertThat(result, either(is(1)).or(is(2)).or(is(3))))
```