# How do I assert to accept one of multiple possible values in JUnit

Tags: testing, junit, automated-tests, assert, multiple-value

I have a test that returns some value after completion. The returned value is a `String` and can have one of several possible values based on some if condition in the test.
But in the `assert` statement I can check only one of the `Expected` values not both.

How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple correct results with Hamcrest (is there a or-matcher?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152714/multiple-correct-results-with-hamcrest-is-there-a-or-matcher)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of any Hamcrest question, because the OP does not mention using Hamcrest, nor is Hamcrest the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

I will use [AssertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/wiki) for this

```
 assertThat(value).isIn(expected1, expected2, expected3);
```

The code is much simpler than with Hamcrest.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to save the result and then run a Jtest that the result was in an array of accepted solutions.

E.g:

```
`it("Test Message", () => {
    const result = testFunction(inputValue);
    assert.equal((result in [possibeResult1, possibleResult2, ...]), true);
});`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Answers should include an explanation of the solution/answer, not just code. When answering old questions with existing accepted answers, take some time to explain why your answer is different or an improvement/update to the other answers.

Comment: One possible improvement to this answer would be to reference source material in a trusted source. for example https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-junit-asserts-can